# Why igCombo not working in dynamically added page in iframe?

Tags: jquery, master-pages, infragistics, ignite-ui, igcombo

```
pages structures as 

-> MasterPage
-> ContentPage 
-> iframe 
-> aspx.page in iframe
```

When I'm binding igCombo with control on master page then it displays igCombo box but when binding igCombo with control which is on aspx page inside iframe then throwing an error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property pageYOffset' of undefined`.[image]

Comment: Which file is the exception coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code that you have provided an image of. This is not part of the `igCombo` source, but rather of the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/055cb7534e2dcf7ee8ad145be83cb2d74b5331c7/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L9677). You are probably experiencing this issue only under a specific browser. Anyways, the thing I suggest is changing the version of `jQuery`.